# How to add two separate layers on the top of one layer using pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I want to add two separate layers on the top of one layer (or a pre-trained model) Is that possible for me to do using Pytorch?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when defining your model's `forward` function, you can specify how the inputs should be passed through the layers.

For example:

```py
def forward(self, X):
    X = self.common_layer(X)
    X = self.activation_fn(X)
    Xa = self.layer_a(X)
    Xb = self.layer_b(X)
    # now combine outputs of the parallel layers however you please
    return self.combining_layer(torch.cat([Xa, Xb]))
```

Where `forward` is a member of `MyNet`:

```py
class MyNet(nn.Module):
   def __init__(self):
       # define common_layer, activation_fn, layer_a, layer_b, and combining_layer
```

## Training

The model should be trained, just like any other pytorch model.

Because the combined output goes through both `layer_a` and `layer_b`, computing gradient of the loss will optimize paramaters for both layers. The layers will be optimized seperately as the parameters of their object are independent.

For example.

```py
model = MyNet()
...
optimizer.zero_grad()
predictions = model(input_batch)
loss = my_loss_fn(predictions, ground_truth)
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. But I have one more question, how to train them at the same time in a separate manner?

Comment: @YukiWang I've updated the answer to address training.

Comment: @YukiWang could you please confirm the answer as a solution then?

Comment: Alright. Sorry that I am new here, I just figured out how to accept an answer.